# Change css in Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I’m having problems with the migration of styles from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4, in one of my views I have the background configured in one color, and in a form I have 3 ion-items, the first problem I have is that I modify the item- inner to have no borders and does not work and the second is the ion-toggle takes the background color of my view by default and if I change it, it takes the value as correct checked

Html:

```
<ion-header>

</ion-header>

<ion-content no-bounce>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo" padding-horizontal>
    <ion-row class="img">
        <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" alt="Movistar">
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="click">
        Click!
    </ion-row>
    </div>
    <form novalidate padding-horizontal margin-top>
    <ion-list padding-horizontal>
        <ion-item class="custom-item">
        <ion-label fixed>Usuario</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" name="username" class="invalid" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <!--<ion-label padding-horizontal color="danger">&#10060; Campo requerido</ion-label>-->

        <ion-item class="custom-item" margin-top>
        <ion-label fixed>Contraseña</ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="eye-off"></ion-icon>
        <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <!--<ion-label padding-horizontal  color="danger">&#10060; Campo requerido</ion-label>-->

        <ion-item id="remember">
        <ion-label>Recordar credenciales?</ion-label>
        <ion-toggle color="success"></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>

        <div>
        <ion-button type="submit" expand="block" class="button-ingresar">Ingresar</ion-button>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
    </form>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Css:

```
.toolbar-background {
    border: none !important;
}

.logo {

    .img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 98px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px var(--padding);

        img {
            margin-top: 50px;
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }

    .click {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Custom';
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0px var(--padding);
        line-height: 4rem;
    }
}

form {
    .password-eye {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #remember {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;

        .item-inner {
            border: none !important;
        }
    }

    ion-item {
        border: none !important;
    }

    .custom-item {
        color: white;
        border-radius: var(--border-radius);
        background-color: var(--custom-primary-contrast);
        border: none !important;

        .item-inner {
            border: none !important;
        }
    }

    .button {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

ion-content {
    --ion-background-color: var(--custom-primary);
}

.button-ingresar {
    --background: var(--custom-secondary) !important;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the first image what you have and the second what you want ? also you mind adding the html

Comment: Both images is what I do not want, the inputs are with border and by css (which worked in Ionic 3) does not remove them. And the second thing is that the toggle takes the background color of the ion-content thing that I do not want.

Comment: any chance of the html ?

Comment: add it html @IraW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it takes some tinkering going from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4.
I can recommend using their documentation, where the new css variables are shown.

For your specific use case, i think these 2 css variables will fix it.

```
 --inner-border-width: 0; // The old .item-inner border fixer.
```

and

```
 --background: var(--custom-primary-contrast);
```

same issues come with border-radius on some components

```
 --border-radius: var(--border-radius);
```

Link to the css variables for [ion-toggle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle#css-custom-properties)

Link to the css variables for [ion-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties)

Hope it helped!